Examples of differences between one- and two-sided shift spaces
The Scholarpedia article on Symbolic dynamics states

... However, one may also consider the one-sided $\mathcal A$-shift $\mathcal A^{\mathbb N}$ . For simplicity, concepts in this article are described in the two-sided context. Most of the definitions adapt naturally to the one-sided setting, although there are some significant differences in results.

What are some examples of differences?
I don't imagine the topology is different (the induced topology from the usual metric on shift spaces), so any differences must be a consequence of some additional structure. Is this correct?

The two spaces will be homeomorphic, but the shift in the two-sided case is invertible while it is not in the one-sided case. The two systems are therefore not isomorphic as dynamical systems.
Another big difference is the notion of periodicity. In the one-sided case there is the notion of eventually periodic, which to my knowledge does not exist in the two-sided case.
Periodicity of an element $x\in \mathcal{A}^\mathbb{Z}$, means that there exist a $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n+p}=x_{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Whereas, $x\in  \mathcal{A}^ \mathbb{N}$ is evenetually periodic if there exist $N,p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n+p}=x_n$, for any $n>N$. Both have finite orbits, but the asymptotic behavior can obviously be different.
There are several other properties and classifications which differ in the one-sided vs the two-sided cases, like minimality and transitivity.
